# Unable to use PDFLib Adapter with latest dompdf 0.7.0

Tags: php, dompdf, pdflib

I am using DomPDF with PDFLib as backend.

Recently I am trying to upgrade my application to use dompdf from 0.6.0 to 0.7.0.

But it is giving exception in following file :

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/master/src/Adapter/PDFLib.php#L213

```
$families = $dompdf->getFontMetrics->getFontFamilies();
```

Exception :

```
[Dompdf\Exception, 0]
Invalid property: getFontMetrics
```

Can anyone let me know what is this error about ?

Below is the sample php script that I am trying to run :

```
<?php
require_once('dompdf/autoload.inc.php');

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

$options = new Options();
$options->set(array(
        'pdfBackend'=>'PDFLib',
        'defaultMediaType'=>'print',
        'defaultPaperSize'=>'A4',
        'defaultFont'=>'arial',
        'enable_html5_parser'=>true,
        'enable_font_subsetting'=>true
));

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs in 0.7.0 with regard to PDFLib. The next release should address those issues (commit [3fd379b](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/commit/3fd379b76c6836d64afed712d559f71b6355345a) addresses this particular issue). No release date is currently set, though I would expect to see it by this fall.

Relevant discussion is in issue [#1222](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1222).